# Error When Switching Tenant Using Apartment Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, multi-tenant, apartment-gem, apartments

i am getting error when execute `Apartment::Tenant.switch!("tenant_name")` even when the tenant were exists.

When i run Apartment::tenant_names,it return an array contain `["murah5","rahmatullah","test"]` then i run `Apartment::Tenant.switch!("murah5")` it return :

`Apartment::TenantNotFound: One of the following schema(s) is invalid: "murah5" "public" from /Users/fourtyonestudio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/apartment-1.2.0/lib/apartment/adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:72:in`rescue in connect_to_new'`

can you help me with this case ?

Answer (score 1):

This error may be due to the missing schema in the database for that name

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/40045/how-do-i-list-all-schemas-in-postgresql

Answer (score 0):

you can make a method in the model (which creates the tenants)

```
     class Tenant < ApplicationRecord
       def self.switch(subdomain)
         Apartment::Tenant.switch! subdomain
       end
     end
```

then you can switch your subdomain from rails console like

```
  Tenant.switch('app')
```

check you current subdomain by `Apartment::Tenant.current`